# man -k and apropos cannot find pages in section 3 in Catalina

Tags: macos, terminal, catalina, command-line

For example, run `apropos printf`:

```
Printf(3o)               - Formatted output functions
Stdlib.Printf(3o)        - no description
gprintf(1), printf(1)    - format and print data
format(ntcl)             - Format a string in the style of sprintf
fwkpfv(1)                - FireWire kprintf viewer
printf(1)                - formatted output
xprintf(5)               - extensible printf
```

`printf(3)` is not listed, but `man 3 printf` can find that man page.

Meanwhile, stderr prints many errors like this one:

```
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib: Not a directory
```

What should I do to make `apropos` and `man -k` work properly?

Answer (score 1):

Saw a handy shell trick posted in Apple Discussions to get rid of the hundreds of error messages whenever doing a `man -k` or `apropos` type inquiry:

```
apo() { apropos "$@" 2> /dev/null; }

myman() { man "$@" 2> /dev/null; }
```

See https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250812698 for the discussion.

Comment: Nice call suppressing the stderr, but shouldn't apropos find `printf(3` to be proper functioning? +1 for making the error clearer and maybe the OP feels proper is just suppressing the errors.